# List Leave Dates and Leave type for each month according to the current year?

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to list Leave details (date,leave type) of each month of the current year.
Eg: From January to December , select the dates for each month according to the LeaveDetails sql table
and also select the leave type for each date, the LeaveDetails table has columns -> empId,LeaveId,LeaveType,fromdate,toDate,status,FinalStatus,isDeleted.

How can I achieve this in SQL?

```
DECLARE @empId INT = 1344

DECLARE @Calendar TABLE (MonthNumber INT);

INSERT INTO @Calendar (MonthNumber)
VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10),(11),(12);


WITH DateCTE AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        empId,
        MONTH(fromDate) AS leaveMonth,
        fromDate AS leaveDate
    FROM
        _LeaveDetails
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT
        empId,MONTH(toDate) AS leaveMonth,
        toDate AS leaveDate
    FROM
       _LeaveDetails
)

SELECT
    c.MonthNumber AS leaveMonth,
    @empId AS empId,
    ISNULL(
        STUFF(
            (
                SELECT
                    ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), leaveDate, 103)
                FROM
                    DateCTE AS innerCTE
                WHERE
                    innerCTE.empId = @empId
                    AND innerCTE.leaveMonth = c.MonthNumber
                FOR
                    XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, ''
        ), '-') AS LeaveDates
FROM
    @Calendar AS c
LEFT JOIN
    DateCTE AS outerCTE ON c.MonthNumber = outerCTE.leaveMonth
                        AND outerCTE.empId = @empId
GROUP BY
    c.MonthNumber
ORDER BY
    leaveMonth;
```

I've tried this to get the leave dates for each month, i want to join few more tables with _Leavedetails table and do some 'where' conditions and select the leave type for each date , How can i achieve this?

Comment: Please update your question with sample data for your source table and the result you are trying to achieve. Asking how to "join few more tables with _Leavedetails table and do some 'where' conditions" is far too broad - you need to provide the specific details of the table(s) you want to join to and the result you want to achieve, again with sample data for all the tables